# how is high and low not changing with user input

Tags: python-3.x

doing project from this youtube vedio and it does not seem to be working.
https://youtu.be/8ext9G7xspg
the finish coode is at 19:49

my problem is when I run it low says at 1 and high says at 100.
any help would be welcome.

```
    def computer_guess(x):
        low=1
        high=x
        feedback=''
        while feedback!='c':
            print(f'high:{high} low:{low} feedback:{feedback}')
            if low !=high:
                guess=random.randint(low,high)
            else:
                guess=low
            feedback=input(f'Is the {guess} to high(h),to low(l), or correct(c)?? ').lower
            if feedback=='h':
                high=guess-1
           
            elif feedback=='l':
                low=guess+1
         
        print(f'yay, the comptuer geussed the number, {guess},correctly!')

    computer_guess(100)
```

i was expecting was low and hight to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is to issues with your code.

1. Than you use the lower class you have to call it correctly. Classes are called with () at the end. So correct way is lower().
2. The logic is not correct. If the feedback is "l" you need to lower the high input and not raise the low value. And the same issue you have if the feedback is "h".

Comment: yes it was cuz I forgot the () in lower thank you